# How to count the number of goroutine in runnable state

Tags: go, concurrency, runtime, runnable, goroutine

I am testing my Go application. Right now I'm getting some information, but I wanted to know how to know the exact number (given some time instant) of **goroutines in the runnable state**: the function `NumGoroutine()` of the `runtime` package returns the number of goroutines that currently exist (which are many more than those in the *runnable* state!).

This is my function which prints the goroutine number every second:

```
func count() {
    for {
        fmt.Println("Number of runnable goroutines: ", runtime.NumGoroutine())
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the result is not good (the number of goroutines in the program is constantly growing, and I know that so many goroutines cannot be active at the same time!). This page: https://golang.org/doc/diagnostics.html says that `debug.Stack` *returns the current stack trace. Stack trace is useful to see how many goroutines are currently running, what they are doing, and whether they are blocked or not.*

If I print `debug.Stack()` (instead of runtime.NumGoroutine()) the result changes completely (every second it always prints the same stack!). My question is: is `len(debug.Stack())` the correct number of goroutines in the *runnable* state? It seems to me not, since this number is constant.
How do I get the right information?

Comment: Your function doesn't print the number of goroutines, it prints a static string (or would, if it would even compile, which it won't, because of the unused variable `x`). `len(debug.Stack())` has no relation to the number of runnable goroutines. As [the documentation for `debug.Stack` states](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/#Stack), it returns the stack trace **of the goroutine that calls it**, so if you call it in the loop, yes the trace will always be the same. I'm not aware of any call to get the number of runnable goroutines, which is an internal scheduler implementation detail.

Comment: I'm afraid _this_ is not currently possible. The closest thing is debugging under [`GOTRACE=schedtrace=X`](https://golang.org/doc/diagnostics.html#godebug). You might find [this explanation of `schedtrace`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/05/10/debugging-performance-issues-in-go-programs) useful.

Comment: Part of the problem is that the entire concept of a goroutine "in runnable state" is an internal implementation detail of the current version of the scheduler; it is not part of the spec. It could change at any point in the future, on any or all platforms, and any stdlib call to retrieve that detail would be broken, violating the compatibility promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend to use this way (because that's how it works inside runtime and might be changed at future), but in testing purposes would be fine:
https://play.golang.org/p/6gi26PF3iTT

As you can see, *running* and *runnable* states are the different states.